# How to get the Alternative text for "Hyperlink or Picture" field Type in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jslink, hyperlink, client-side-rendering

I have a field in my SharePoint list of type Hyperlink.

I want to format the list view so that all the items in it will display as bullet items.

I am using JSLink and below is my code. I want the DOM property URL.DESC. When I tried `overrideCtx.CurrentItem.URL.desc` it is not working.

However it is showing in the DOM.

[image]

Code:

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
     overrideCtx.Templates.Header = " " +
        "<hr><ul id='unorderedlist'>";

    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "</ul>";
    overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 103;
    overrideCtx.OnPreRender = preRenderHandler;
    overrideCtx.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function CustomItem(overrideCtx) {
    var ret = "<li>"+ overrideCtx.CurrentItem.URL + "</li>";
    //console.log("Testqwew"+ret);
    return ret;
}
// The preRenderHandler attends the OnPreRender event
function preRenderHandler(ctx) {

    // Override the default title with user input.
    //ctx.ListTitle = prompt("Type a title", ctx.ListTitle);
}

// The postRenderHandler attends the OnPostRender event
function postRenderHandler(ctx) {

    // You can manipulate the DOM in the postRender event
    var ulObj;
    var i, j;

    ulObj = document.getElementById("unorderedlist");

    // Reverse order the list.
    for (i = 1; i < ulObj.children.length; i++) {
        var x = ulObj.children[i];
        for (j = 1; j < ulObj.children.length; j++) {
            var y = ulObj.children[j];
            if(x.innerText<y.innerText){                  
                ulObj.insertBefore(y, x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
var urlDesc = overrideCtx.CurrentItem['URL.desc'];
```

You can create a link like:

```
var urlLink = ctx.overrideCtx.URL;
var urlDesc = ctx.overrideCtx['URL.desc'];
var appendlnk = "<a href=" + urlLink + " target='_blank'>" + urlDesc + "</a>";
```

**Source**: [How to get the description of Hyperlink column of Custom List using JSLink](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/243607d3-fe38-4b79-afde-0055840b5a20/how-to-get-the-description-of-hyperlink-column-of-custom-list-using-jslink?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: You made my day very simple and happy :-)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the short answer, but this is how you get the URL's description:

```
ctx.CurrentItem["URL.desc"]
```